# Rails 7 "Getting Started with Rails" what is the prefered way to validate comments?

Tags: ruby, validation, comments, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm new to rails. Appreciate any help.
I'm trying to extend functionality of the Blog, described in the [official Rails 7 guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) with comments validation.
Here is my [github repo link](https://github.com/anega/blog/tree/comments) for the project code.
What is the right way to add validation to the comments and **show error messages on the frontend** after submitting invalid form?

Setup
ubuntu - 22.04
rvm - 1.29.12
ruby - 3.1.4p223
rails - 7.0.4.3

Currently if I add these validations on the Comment model validation doesn't work. When I submit an empty comment form it just redirects me to the post page.

/app/models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  validates :author, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

Also tried to handle comment saving in the `comments_controller`. But it saves the comment with an empty `:author` and `:body` fields.

/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render @post, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with model: [@post, @post.comments.build] do |form| %>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= form.label :author, class: 'form-label' %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :author, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'John Doe' %>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= form.label :body, class: 'form-label' %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :body, class: 'form-control', rows: 3 %>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= form.submit 'Add comment', class: 'btn btn-outline-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here are some visualization that i want to achieve(I've just add some html through dev tools). First screenshot - post page before comment form submission, just clean page. Second screenshot(what I want to ahive) - the same page after i submit comment form with empty Author and Body fields.

[First screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO1aP.png)

[Second screenshot(this is what I want comments form to be like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC9bQ.png)

Comment: [Your comment model](https://github.com/anega/blog/blob/main/app/models/comment.rb) has no validations, are you sure you saved the file?

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention, i didn't push the validation code yet. But i'm sure I have the code from my question locally.

Comment: Recent code from the question is in the repo, the link in the question leads to dedicated branch.

Comment: Add your form template.

Comment: Done. 
I've tried to look up for the errors somewhere inside `@comment` or `@post.comments` to show on the page after invalid form submission, but there is no `@comment` object on the page after form submission and redirect and new(invalid) comment was not added to the `@post.comments`.

Comment: Was about to write that I don't see any problem, but then I noticed it. See answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make these two changes to your CommentsController class `create` method when the save fails:

1. Re-fetch the post: `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])`
2. Change the render line to: `render '/posts/show', status: :unprocessable_entity`

The reason we need to re-fetch the post is that when the post's show view is re-rendered (in `/posts/show.html.erb`), the `<%= render @post.comments %>` line in the show view will list out all the comments for the post - which will include the new "failing" comment unless we do the re-fetch before rendering on fail.

So that's the first part of the solution. The next is displaying the error message above the comment form and re-populating the comment form's author and body with their original values. To make that happen, we need to do the following in `/posts/show.html.erb`

First, to render the comment form (in your `<h4>Add a comment</h4>` section), do the following:

`<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { comment: @comment } %>`

This passes the comment down to the comment partial view (`/comments/_form.html.erb`) for use. Here's a sample of that partial view that will accomplish the goals:

```
<p style="color: red"><%= comment ? comment.errors.full_messages.to_sentence : nil %></p>

<%= form_with model: [ @post, @post.comments.build ] do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :author %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag 'comment[author]', comment&.author %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :body %><br>
    <%= text_area_tag 'comment[body]', comment&.body %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The Safe Navigation operator (&.) checks to see if the object is nil. So, if there is a valid comment for the form (which will only be the case on failed re-render) then display the original data, otherwise, the fields will be empty. You could similarly use the `&.` syntax on the error message, but you'd need to add it to each property - so I left the "long" version instead.

Now, when any of your comment model validations fail, an error message will be displayed and the original contents of your failing comment will be re-populated in their respective fields.

[comment error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ItEK.png)

As a final "clean-up", you could consider passing a local `post` to the `/comments/_form.html.erb` rather than accessing `@post` directly in the partial.

Answer (score 0):

One option is validate params before saving like this:

Creating a method to check if all params are not blank.

Then, you call befeore_action for this method before the action to create "comment".

Inside create you validate if the method returns true or false.

If true it redirects to post page noticing user the comment has not being save, else the create methods follow its flow.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :comment_params_empty, only: [:create]

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)

        if comment_params_empty
            flash[:notice] = "Comment not saved!"
            redirect_to @post
        else
            if @comment.save
                redirect_to @post
            else
                render @post, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
        end
    end

    private
        def comment_params_empty
            comment_params.values.all?(&:blank?)
        end
end
```

In this case, I'm only considering create, but you'll need to consider other steps of your CRUD system.

Comment: Thank you for advice. This way doesn't allow me to append error messages on the every form field that has an error. And I cannot have advantages that model validation gives.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I totally missed the `render @post`. You're literally telling it to render the post page on failure :)  Change that to `render :new, status...`

Comment: Thank you for help) as i can see this pushes me to create a template under `/app/views/comments/new.html.erb` that will render `..../_form.html.erb`, so after submitting comment form it will redirect me to the page that has a form, but that is not what i really need. Comments form(as well as all `@post.comments` collection) are now rendered on the post page. So it would be great to stay on the same page(with the post content and related comments) but only update the new comment form with error messages. I'll try to add some screenshots to provide some visualization of what i want to achieve.

Comment: Then render that page

Comment: When I'm rendering that page i don't have the `@comment` object that was previously submitted(with errors empty Author or empty Body)

Comment: You obviously do have that `@comment` because you're in the else for trying to `save` precisely that

Comment: I do have `@comment` in the comments_controller.rb `create` action, but in the false brunch of `if` i redirect to `@post` and i do not have it there. I redirect to post because i have the layout where comments and comment form are located not on the separate page, but directly on the post page(`PostController->show` action). So i ether need to pass invalid `@comment` to the `PostController->show` or rerender the comment form 'dirty' with validation errors.

Comment: Another way I think of is to handle this with Turbo frames to reload only the comment form with invalid comment and its errors. This way i can pass `@comment` object directly from CommentController. But I don't get it yet..)

Comment: No, you don't redirect to post, you **render** post, so all the instance variables you've set (including `@comment`, with its `.errors`) are available there, in that view.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work for me. When I try to access `@comment.errors` inside comment form partial(`app/views/comments/_form.html.erb`) it gives me "NoMethodError in Posts#show. undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass". So it looks like i don't have `@comment` after render.

Comment: When do you get that, after submitting the form, or on the first render? You didn't show your `PostsController#show` method that displays the form initially, obviously that would have to also set a `@comment` ivar

Comment: I've tried to set `@comment = @comment || Comment.new` inside `PostController#show`, but it didn't pass the value of invalid @comment object from the `CommentController#create`

Comment: Y'know actually, I think the `render @post` will be rendering a post partial, you should do an explicit `render "posts/show", status...`